# Convert Hooks to a Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am kinda new to React and I am developing an app integrating Google Maps.
My code is working using Hooks but now I wanted to convert it to a class component but I was having a hard time doing it. I am very confused with the useEffect, useRef and useState. Here is my attempt but I'm getting errors. Can someone help me convert it correctly?

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './Map.css';
import { IMapState } from './IMapState';
import { IMapProps } from './IMapProps';


type GoogleLatLng = google.maps.LatLng;
type GoogleMap = google.maps.Map;

export class Map3 extends React.Component<IMapProps, IMapState> {


constructor(props: IMapProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {

        mapType: google.maps.MapTypeId,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
}

public render(): JSX.Element {
    const {
        mapType,
        mapTypeControl
    } = this.state;


const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
const [map, setMap] = useState<GoogleMap>();

const startMap = (): void => {
    if (!map) {
        defaultMapStart();
    }
};
useEffect(startMap, [map]);


const defaultMapStart = (): void => {
    const defaultAddress = new google.maps.LatLng(40.166013499, -82.9071); //Ohio LatLong        
    initMap(5, defaultAddress);
};


const initMap = (zoomLevel: number, address: GoogleLatLng): void => {
    if (ref.current) {
        setMap(
            new google.maps.Map(ref.current, {
                zoom: zoomLevel,
                center: address,
                mapTypeControl: mapTypeControl,
                streetViewControl: false,
                rotateControl: false,
                scaleControl: true,
                fullscreenControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControl: true,
                gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
                mapTypeId: mapType,
                draggableCursor: 'pointer',
            })
        );
    }

};

return (
        <div ref={ref} className="map-container"></div>
);
};

}
```

When I'm calling it in another TSX file, it looks like this but this is erroring out:

```
                            {scriptLoaded && (
                            <Map3
                                mapType={google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
                                mapTypeControl={true}
                            />
                        )}
```

It says: Type '{ mapType: MapTypeId; mapTypeControl: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
Property 'mapType' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you mind including a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt at conversion to class-based component? What issues are you having? What isn't working? `useState` hooks all go into the single `this.state` object and the `useEffect` hooks split/merge into `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong code. I already edited my question. @DrewReese